# Is it ok to edit a question to the point that it is no longer the same question?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

If you ask a question and the question is a bad one for whatever reason, and upon learning this edit it to the point that it's not even the same question anymore, is that ok?

[This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/130242/what-is-the-most-optimal-build-for-lucians-ultimate-to-do-the-most-damage) question is what sparked my interest.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that edit hasn't changed the fundamental meaning of the post...

Comment: @kalian yes it has, radically

Comment: This is kind of the whole point of the close/reopen process. I fail to see the problem.

Comment: I'm not saying there *is* a problem, I'm asking *if* there is a problem. I kinda felt a *new* question should be asked, rather than super editing the old one

Comment: Care to explain how the edit has "radically changed" the meaning of the post? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @Ender honestly, since everybody around here assumes I'm trolling whenever I say something that disagrees with them - there is no radical change here, the overall meaning of the post remains the same after the edits - it's still asking the same question

Comment: I feel it's fundamentally different because the pre-edit asks for the maximum damage the skill can do, and the post-edit asks for an optimal build so it can do the most damage. Each question is completely different as I see it, to the point they can each be posted separately without being flagged as duplicates.

Comment: @Ender I'm with kalina here. The intent appears to be the same, just better expressed. Different words, different framing of the issue, but the same end point.

Comment: I just realised that sounds like criticism of asking the question, when that's not my intention. This is a valid concern, and the right place to bring it. This does happen and needs to be addressed, so being concerned and aware of it is good. That particular question's edit is just slightly on the right side of being OK rather than bad, is all.

Comment: You're talking of editing by the person who asked it - I read this to see the justifications for 3rd parties to mutate questions beyond their original intent :P. Don't see why asker can't modify his Q. to elicit better replies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### In General

If a question is put On Hold, then it is almost certainly OK; part of the reason questions are put On Hold instead of Closed these days is to give the people who wrote them an opportunity to rewrite them so as to be useful, even if the edits are a bit drastic. But the question you linked doesn't seem to have ever been put On Hold, according to the revision history.

If the question already has good answers, and the editing might serve to make those answers invalid, then the edit might well need reverting. These are commonly called ["Chameleon Questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions), and Meta Stack Overflow already has [a number of discussions on that topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=chameleon). The short answer is generally "If it's mostly the same question, but a bit broader or a bit more in-depth, it's probably OK, otherwise play it by ear". But the question you linked doesn't seem to have had an answer at the time it was edited (or else any answers have been deleted, and I thus can't see them).

#### In this specific case

In fact, the post in question hasn't been edited terribly radically. It was originally about the maximum amount of damage that could be dealt by a specific ability ("how much damage would you deal with Lucian's ultimate?"), but now instead it asks for the build needed to maximize damage with that ability ("What would you have to build to get the most damage out of The Culling?"). All the edit did was preclude the near-infinite list of debuffs, items, etc. that other players could have that might affect the damage dealt, limiting the question to something that can be answered. By limiting the question to items, buffs, etc. that Lucian can get himself, the question became answerable.

<sub>Well, technically the question changed. Before, it was looking for the number, and didn't actually ask how, so an answer of "10324" or the like would have been horrible, but technically correct, whereas now it asks for a build, but not the number. This is extremely pedantic. Oh, and it technically no longer asks specifically about hitting a Champion. Not a big change.</sub>

Comment: Just to clarify, because people keep missing it: "closed" and "on hold" are not two different things.